# Context Sublayout of Rendering Parameter

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I am using a rendering paramater template in a layout and need to work out the sublayout that the current parameters are attached to so that I can read a field from the sublayout in this context.

I have found this example

[Set queryable source on Rendering Parameter Template field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18009470/set-queryable-source-on-rendering-parameter-template-field)

but it only pulls back the context layout and not sublayout.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, what you need is answered here: [Sitecore: How to use sublayout parameters from codebehind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949214/sitecore-how-to-use-sublayout-parameters-from-codebehind?rq=1)

Otherwise, perhaps clarify the question a bit more? :-)